# Setting margins so that text is centered on a page

Tags: margins, amsart

How do I center the text on the page?  The text is flush against the right margin.  (I have more text. On the second page, the text is also flush against the right margin.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}


\centerline{\Large{\textbf{Distance between a Point and a Line}}} \vskip0.5in


\noindent {\bf Definition} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
{\em $\ell$ is a line, and $P = (x_{\circ}, \, y_{\circ})$ is a point that is not on $\ell$. The {\bf distance} between $P$ and $\ell$ is the distance between $P$ and the intersection of $\ell$ and the line through $P$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$. (According to the Pythagorean Theorem, it is less than the distance between $P$ and any other point on $\ell$.)}
\end{minipage}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent {\bf Theorem} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
{\em $\ell$ is a line, and $P = (x_{\circ}, \, y_{\circ})$ is a point that is not on $\ell$. If $Ax + By + C = 0$ is an equation for $\ell$, the distance between $P$ and $\ell$ is}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\vert Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + C \vert}{\sqrt{A^{2} + B^{2}}} .
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\vskip0.2in

\noindent {\bf Demonstration} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent An equation for the line through $P$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$ is $-Bx + Ay + (Bx_{\circ} - Ay_{\circ}) = 0$, and the lines intersect at $Q = (x_{1}, \, y_{1})$ if, and only if,
\begin{equation*}
x_{1} = \frac{B^{2}x_{\circ} - ABy_{\circ} - AC}{A^{2} + B^{2}}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
y_{1} = \frac{-ABx_{\circ} + A^{2}y_{\circ} - BC}{A^{2} + B^{2}} .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{align*}
\big\vert\overline{PQ}\big\vert^{2}
&= \left(\frac{B^{2}x_{\circ} - ABy_{\circ} - AC}{A^{2} + B^{2}} - x_{\circ}\right)^{2}
+ \left(\frac{-ABx_{\circ} + A^{2}y_{\circ} - BC}{A^{2} + B^{2}} - y_{\circ}\right)^{2} \\
&= \left(\frac{-A^{2}x_{\circ} - ABy_{\circ} - AC}{A^{2} + B^{2}}\right)^{2}
+ \left(\frac{-ABx_{\circ} - B^{2}y_{\circ} - BC}{A^{2} + B^{2}}\right)^{2} \\
&= \frac{(A^{2}x_{\circ} + ABy_{\circ} + AC){\vphantom{A^{2}}}^{2} + (ABx_{\circ} + B^{2}y_{\circ} + BC){\vphantom{B^{2}}}^{2}}{(A^{2} + B^{2}){\vphantom{A^{2}}}^{2}} \\
&= \frac{A^{2}(Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + C)^{2} + B^{2}(Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + B)^{2}}{(A^{2} + B^{2}){\vphantom{A^{2}}}^{2}} \\
&= \frac{(A^{2} + B^{2})(Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + C)^{2}}{(A^{2} + B^{2}){\vphantom{A^{2}}}^{2}} \\
&= \frac{(Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + C)^{2}}{A^{2} + B^{2}} ,
\intertext{and}
\big\vert\overline{PQ}\big\vert &= \frac{\vert Ax_{\circ} + By_{\circ} + C \vert}{\sqrt{A^{2} + B^{2}}} . \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{align*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{Quotes from Alan Shepard} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent It's a very sobering feeling to be up in space and realize that one's safety factor was determined by the lowest bidder on a government contract. \\
\noindent It's been a long way, but we're here.
\vskip0.25in

\noindent \textbf{Quotes from Yogi Berra} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent Baseball is ninety percent mental and the other half is physical.
\noindent You can observe a lot by just watching.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\calclayout` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: `\centerline`, `\bf` and `\vskip` shouldn't be used in latex (and `\noindent` only rarely)

Comment: @egreg  I have not seen this command.  Since it has "calc" in its name, it suggests (to me) that it is used in files with equations that will be typeset in display mode.  Can this command be used if I were going to make a file for just keeping a diary?

Comment: @Adelyn It's a specific command of the `amsart` class, it computes the pagination parameters so that the text block is centered.

Comment: @egreg   Suppose that I had a line consisting of a short sentence.  "Alice in Wonderland is a tale written by Lewis Carroll."  This would not span the width of the page.  Would it be centered?!

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not really clear. Do you know about the `center` environment?

Comment: @egreg  Suppose I were writing a file consisting of a play.  Often, characters have a line consisting of a single word.  Can I use `\calclayout` in the preamble and have it left-aligned.

Comment: @Adelyn Sorry, I can't follow you.

Comment: @Adelyn `\calclayout` is for centering the ***text block*** on the page. It has nothing to do with the typesetting of paragraphs in the text. Why are you talking about a play and show a mathematical text? Please, change your question so it reflects what you're about.

Comment: @egreg  I just edited the post.  I put some quotes by two famous Americans.  I don't know what you mean by "centering the text block."

Comment: @egreg  May you give me a link to read about `\calclayout`?

Comment: `texdoc amsart`

Comment: The text block is the total area available for regular content on the page. In your document this is 6.1in wide and 9in high. This allows margins around the page - left margin, right margin, top and bottom. Regular content goes in the text block. Page numbers and headers etc. may go outside the text block. Think about a novel. The text block is where all the stuff you read is. The page numbers and headers are outside this. If you centre the text block, the margins are made equal i.e. left margin = right margin etc. Centring particular bits of text *within* the text block is different.

Comment: @cfr -- `texdoc amsclass` is the correct reference.  even there, `\calclayout` isn't very well documented.  the general layouts of ams document classes weren't really meant to be tinkered with by anyone who wasn't familiar with the "internal" coding; it was both a policy decision and a practical one based on the (at the time) limited memory space. (it has also been a thorn in our side.)  i'll write an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**short answer:** add `\calclayout` to your preamble after resetting the
page dimensions.

**details:**
unlike the basic `article`, `book` and `proc` classes,
ams document classes (among them `amsart`) horizontally center the
contents of the page on the output medium.  since a goal of the ams
classes is to enforce ams publication style, this positioning is
"locked in" so that attempts by authors to modify page dimensions will
be immediately obvious to the ams production staff.

the "lock-in" mechanism is a routine called by the command `\calclayout`.

the horizontal positioning is accomplished by subtracting the `\textwidth`
from the `\paperwidth`, and dividing by two to establish equal side margins.
(it's actually a bit more complicated, as adjustments are made to ensure that the "canonical" `1in` indentation to the left is taken into account,
and that the final left-hand margin always has a positive minimum value.)

vertical positioning is more complicated.  the prescribed `\textheight`
is assumed to include the `\headheight` and `\headsep`, so those are
subtracted from `\textheight`.  further calculations are made using the
`\topmargin` as the "scratch dimension".  first this is set to the `\paperheight`, and then decreased in turn by `\textheight`, `\headheight`,
and `\headsep`.  what remains is divided by two and adjusted to take into
account the "canonical" `1in` top margin, again enforcing a minimum
final top margin.

if a user wishes to reset the page size so that the contents are centered
horizontally, it's necessary to call `\calclayout`.  but owing to the way
the vertical positioning is calculated, unless all the components are reset,
it's not guaranteed that the top and bottom margins will be equal, although
the difference between them will not be great, since the default `\headheight` and `\headsep` are small.

so, as a first cut, simply add `\calclayout` after resetting `\textheight` and `\textwidth`, examine the output (of a full page, not usually the
first page), and if the positioning is not to your liking, also reset
`\headheight` and `\headsep` (and the paper dimensions if not lettersize or
`a4`).

the `geometry` package is not compatible with the ams document classes.
usually, no real errors will be reported, but the results are not likely
to be what is wanted.